# Simple Javascript HTML Replace

Tags: javascript

I know I'm doing something silly.  But I just can't figure it out.  I want to replace some text inside an  tag immediately when the document loads.  I know the function is executing.  But it konks out at the getElementById statement and I don't know why.  The output should say "New Junk".  But instead always says "Original Stuff".

```
<html>
<script>
window.onload = filltip();

  function filltip() {
   alert('xyz');
   var id = 'qourl';
   var txt = 'New Junk';
   //alert('current html=' + document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '?<span class="classic">' + txt +   
'</span>';
  }

</script>
<body>

<a href='#' id='qourl'>Original Stuff</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your onload to this:

```
window.onload = filltip;
```

By writing `window.onload = filltip()`, you are actually calling `filltip` immediately, and using its return value as the onload function (in this case, `undefined`). In general, when you are assigning a function, you never want `()` on it unless the function very specifically returns another function.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me but I tried it and it works.